# if $a \ge b$, and $b \le 2$, can I say $a \ge 2$?

Tags: inequality

Since from $b \le 2$, we can know that the maximum of $b$ is 2, and $a \ge b$, so is this safe or enough to conclude that $a \ge 2$?

Comment: Consider $a = 1.5$ and $b = 1$

Comment: Try some examples of values for $a$ and $b$...

Answer (score 2):

No. Counterexample: $a = 1, b = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Imagine on the real line, what these statements mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. If we only know that $b\le 2$, $b$ could be $-10000000$.

Answer (score 0):

$a \ge b$ means: $a$ is bigger than $b$.

$b \le 2$ means: $2$ is bigger than $b$.

So we imagine three numbers, $a, b,$ and $2$. We know $a$ and $2$ are bigger than $b$. So $b$ is the smallest. But there is no necessary relationship between $a$ and $2$.
For example, $a$ might be $5$ (which is bigger than $2$), or it might be $1$ (which is less than $2$).

Answer (score 0):

$if a≥b$, and $b≤2$, can I say $a≥2
?$

no you need $ b\geq 2$ to conclude by transitive relation that $a\geq 2$

$if a≥b$
, and $b\geq2$
, then $a≥2
$